# Touch support for Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, installation, ubuntu-touch, multi-touch

I have a Hewlett-Packard (HP) AiO 23-f2300a TouchSmart PC and have installed elementaryOS on it, but unfortunately it does not support Touch. And I've just checked out the Ubuntu website and I have to say, I'm really looking forward to downloading Ubuntu!

But I have just one question, which I can't seem to find an answer to. Does the latest version of Ubuntu have Touch support? (This is not a laptop/netbook/notebook, etc - it's a normal all in one desktop computer with full multi-touch support).

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu does have touch support in the uTouch stack. However this touch support does not mean that the entire operating system can be used with touches and gestures.

Touch support has only recently been added and thus most applications do not provide touch support and can only be used with traditional input devices. I use my touch screen with a script that produces touch events but also simulates mouse events when there is only a single touch on the screen. Without this script I cannot use the touch screen in 99% of the applications available for Ubuntu.

So yes there is touch support, but if you want to use standard applications you're pretty much out of luck. Ubuntu cannot be used soley with touch.